# Spring boot Tomcat server not starting due to zip file closed

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I am using spring boot 3.0.2 (tomcat 10.1.5) while started getting an error. I have shared my full stack error.

```
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[/IAMWeb]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:831)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1057)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1100)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getManEntry(JarFile.java:937)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.checkForSpecialAttributes(JarFile.java:1000)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.isMultiRelease(JarFile.java:389)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:68)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:41)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:393)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:328)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:271)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:234)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5144)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use JSPs with Spring Boot 3.0.x you must launch your application with `-Djdk.util.jar.enableMultiRelease=false`, for example:

```
$ java -jar -Djdk.util.jar.enableMultiRelease=false your-application.war
```