# I deployed a spring boot app with tomcat. Running the url in the browser gives Application failed to start error . How to resolve this?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, tomcat, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying a springboot app on azure. It shows deployed successfully but when i enter the url in the browser it gives me application failed to start error everytime ?

My application also contains tomcat to render jsp pages. So then i tried to deployed one simple app without tomcat and it worked fine . But after adding tomcat in it also gives me same error. I tried changing ports, gave startup command but nothing worked .
application logs are as below.

```
2023-05-15T11:32:08.139273507Z    _|_|                                            
2023-05-15T11:32:08.139308107Z  _|    _|  _|_|_|_|  _|    _|  _|  _|_|    _|_|    
2023-05-15T11:32:08.139313407Z  _|_|_|_|      _|    _|    _|  _|_|      _|_|_|_|  
2023-05-15T11:32:08.139317007Z  _|    _|    _|      _|    _|  _|        _|        
2023-05-15T11:32:08.139320907Z  _|    _|  _|_|_|_|    _|_|_|  _|          _|_|_|
2023-05-15T11:32:08.139324507Z 
2023-05-15T11:32:08.139327807Z      J A V A   O N   A P P   S E R V I C E
2023-05-15T11:32:08.139331207Z 
2023-05-15T11:32:08.139334307Z Documentation: https://aka.ms/appservice
2023-05-15T11:32:08.139337607Z 
2023-05-15T11:32:08.139340907Z **NOTE**: No files or system changes outside of /home will persist beyond your application's current session. /home is your application's persistent storage and is shared across all the server instances.
2023-05-15T11:32:08.139347707Z 
2023-05-15T11:32:08.139350907Z 
2023-05-15T11:32:08.139672109Z Updating /etc/ssh/sshd_config to use PORT 2222
2023-05-15T11:32:08.158498691Z Starting ssh service...
2023-05-15T11:32:08.285563646Z ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: DSA 
2023-05-15T11:32:08.694137330Z  * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd
2023-05-15T11:32:08.896999716Z    ...done.
2023-05-15T11:32:08.999859765Z  * sshd is running
2023-05-15T11:32:09.044667760Z ## Printing build info...
2023-05-15T11:32:09.067252659Z                                            PACKAGE |                             VERSION | COMMIT
2023-05-15T11:32:09.067285559Z        Microsoft.AppService.WebsitesExtensionsJava |                          1.0.022547 | 5d33e9c4
2023-05-15T11:32:09.067290859Z                                               self |                         1.0.0228639 | 693c2b72
2023-05-15T11:32:09.067884861Z ## Done printing build info.
2023-05-15T11:32:09.068095462Z Container info: WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID = 08307498aa991c84523184617d17f074bad5139bd2c0710fdf2b1a0ad3d3a9b7 ; WEBSITE_SITE_NAME = smartinventorytest
2023-05-15T11:32:09.090823161Z Add public certificates to keystore if exists...
2023-05-15T11:32:09.091065862Z Add private certificates to keystore if exists...
2023-05-15T11:32:09.091741665Z Configuring max heap = 1253 MB
2023-05-15T11:32:09.175821032Z STARTUP_FILE=
2023-05-15T11:32:09.175988833Z STARTUP_COMMAND=
2023-05-15T11:32:09.176150333Z No STARTUP_FILE available.
2023-05-15T11:32:09.176305034Z No STARTUP_COMMAND defined.
2023-05-15T11:32:09.738843887Z Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx1253M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -javaagent:/agents/java/applicationinsights-agent-codeless.jar
2023-05-15T11:32:10.950209262Z OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
2023-05-15T11:32:36.661153333Z Mangled result from Jar entry point parser is: 2023-05-15 11:32:35.390Z INFO  c.m.applicationinsights.agent - Application Insights Java Agent 3.4.6 started successfully (PID 45, JVM running for 25.629 s)
2023-05-15T11:32:36.661227834Z 2023-05-15 11:32:35.479Z INFO  c.m.applicationinsights.agent - Java version: 17.0.4.1, vendor: Microsoft, home: /opt/java/openjdk
2023-05-15T11:32:36.663417543Z __COM_MICROSOFT_AZURE_APPSERVICE_JARENTRYPOINT_PREFIX__org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher__COM_MICROSOFT_AZURE_APPSERVICE_JARENTRYPOINT_SUFFIX__
2023-05-15T11:32:36.713372862Z Extracted jar entry point. Class name is: 'org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher'
2023-05-15T11:32:36.742933092Z Defaulting to UTF-8
2023-05-15T11:32:36.749596921Z Running command: java -cp /home/site/wwwroot/app.jar:/usr/local/appservice/lib/azure.appservice.jar: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/appservice/logging.properties -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -Dserver.port=80 -XX:ErrorFile=/home/LogFiles/java_error_smartinventorytest_lw0sdlwk000628_%p.log -XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/LogFiles/java_memdump_smartinventorytest_lw0sdlwk000628.log -Duser.dir=/home/site/wwwroot org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
2023-05-15T11:32:36.750310224Z Launched child process with pid: 92
2023-05-15T11:32:36.769582309Z Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx1253M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -javaagent:/agents/java/applicationinsights-agent-codeless.jar
2023-05-15T11:32:36.788062590Z Waiting for main process to exit. GLOBAL_PID_MAIN=92
2023-05-15T11:32:36.789243695Z Waiting for GLOBAL_PID_MAIN == 92
2023-05-15T11:32:37.201911805Z OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
2023-05-15T11:32:53.543964388Z 2023-05-15 11:32:53.496Z INFO  c.m.applicationinsights.agent - Application Insights Java Agent 3.4.6 started successfully (PID 92, JVM running for 16.717 s)
2023-05-15T11:32:53.545481794Z 2023-05-15 11:32:53.544Z INFO  c.m.applicationinsights.agent - Java version: 17.0.4.1, vendor: Microsoft, home: /opt/java/openjdk
2023-05-15T11:33:08.836203647Z 
2023-05-15T11:33:08.837511552Z   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2023-05-15T11:33:08.837528552Z  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2023-05-15T11:33:08.838708157Z ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2023-05-15T11:33:08.838727257Z  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2023-05-15T11:33:08.838732557Z   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2023-05-15T11:33:08.838947258Z  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2023-05-15T11:33:08.857923037Z  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.4)
2023-05-15T11:33:08.865216167Z 
2023-05-15T11:33:10.726461402Z 2023-05-15T11:33:10.564Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] c.e.s.SmartInventoryApplication          : Starting SmartInventoryApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.4.1 with PID 92 (/home/site/wwwroot/app.jar started by root in /home/site/wwwroot)
2023-05-15T11:33:10.757303030Z 2023-05-15T11:33:10.756Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] c.e.s.SmartInventoryApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-05-15T11:33:21.052113071Z 2023-05-15T11:33:21.051Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-05-15T11:33:21.310293128Z 2023-05-15T11:33:21.309Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-05-15T11:33:22.184496304Z 2023-05-15T11:33:22.178Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JPA - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.einfochips.smartinventory.mongorepository.ProductRackRepository; If you want this repository to be a JPA repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: jakarta.persistence.Entity, jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
2023-05-15T11:33:22.445876173Z 2023-05-15T11:33:22.445Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1009 ms. Found 8 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-05-15T11:33:23.027809451Z 2023-05-15T11:33:23.026Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-05-15T11:33:23.044610520Z 2023-05-15T11:33:23.044Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-05-15T11:33:23.130282469Z 2023-05-15T11:33:23.092Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.einfochips.smartinventory.userrepository.OrderItemRepository; If you want this repository to be a MongoDB repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository
2023-05-15T11:33:23.130323169Z 2023-05-15T11:33:23.101Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.einfochips.smartinventory.userrepository.OrderRepository; If you want this repository to be a MongoDB repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository
2023-05-15T11:33:23.130330569Z 2023-05-15T11:33:23.102Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.einfochips.smartinventory.userrepository.InventoryRepository; If you want this repository to be a MongoDB repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository
2023-05-15T11:33:23.130337369Z 2023-05-15T11:33:23.102Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.einfochips.smartinventory.userrepository.CustomerRepository; If you want this repository to be a MongoDB repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository
2023-05-15T11:33:23.130354969Z 2023-05-15T11:33:23.103Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.einfochips.smartinventory.userrepository.SupplierRepository; If you want this repository to be a MongoDB repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository
2023-05-15T11:33:23.130360370Z 2023-05-15T11:33:23.112Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.einfochips.smartinventory.userrepository.UserRepository; If you want this repository to be a MongoDB repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository
2023-05-15T11:33:23.130365470Z 2023-05-15T11:33:23.113Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.einfochips.smartinventory.userrepository.RoleRepository; If you want this repository to be a MongoDB repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository
2023-05-15T11:33:23.130370870Z 2023-05-15T11:33:23.114Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.einfochips.smartinventory.userrepository.ProductRepository; If you want this repository to be a MongoDB repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository
2023-05-15T11:33:23.201258959Z 2023-05-15T11:33:23.181Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 133 ms. Found 1 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2023-05-15T11:33:33.320694911Z 2023-05-15T11:33:33.320Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 80 (http)
2023-05-15T11:33:33.687390964Z x-ms-applog:Informational:base64:SW5pdGlhbGl6aW5nIFByb3RvY29sSGFuZGxlciBbImh0dHAtbmlvLTgwIl0Kc291cmNlOiBvcmcuYXBhY2hlLmNveW90ZS5BYnN0cmFjdFByb3RvY29sCm1ldGhvZDogaW5pdApsb2dnZXI6IG9yZy5hcGFjaGUuY295b3RlLmh0dHAxMS5IdHRwMTFOaW9Qcm90b2NvbA==
2023-05-15T11:33:33.689729674Z x-ms-applog:Informational:base64:U3RhcnRpbmcgc2VydmljZSBbVG9tY2F0XQpzb3VyY2U6IG9yZy5hcGFjaGUuY2F0YWxpbmEuY29yZS5TdGFuZGFyZFNlcnZpY2UKbWV0aG9kOiBzdGFydEludGVybmFsCmxvZ2dlcjogb3JnLmFwYWNoZS5jYXRhbGluYS5jb3JlLlN0YW5kYXJkU2VydmljZQ==
2023-05-15T11:33:33.792184880Z x-ms-applog:Informational:base64:U3RhcnRpbmcgU2VydmxldCBlbmdpbmU6IFtBcGFjaGUgVG9tY2F0LzEwLjEuNV0Kc291cmNlOiBvcmcuYXBhY2hlLmNhdGFsaW5hLmNvcmUuU3RhbmRhcmRFbmdpbmUKbWV0aG9kOiBzdGFydEludGVybmFsCmxvZ2dlcjogb3JnLmFwYWNoZS5jYXRhbGluYS5jb3JlLlN0YW5kYXJkRW5naW5l
applog:Informational:base64:UGF1c2luZyBQcm90b2NvbEhhbmRsZXIgWyJodHRwLW5pby04MCJdCnNvdXJjZTogb3JnLmFwYWNoZS5jb3lvdGUuQWJzdHJhY3RQcm90b2NvbAptZXRob2Q6IHBhdXNlCmxvZ2dlcjogb3JnLmFwYWNoZS5jb3lvdGUuaHR0cDExLkh0dHAxMU5pb1Byb3RvY29s
2023-05-15T11:33:34.943494939Z x-ms-applog:Informational:base64:U3RvcHBpbmcgc2VydmljZSBbVG9tY2F0XQpzb3VyY2U6IG9yZy5hcGFjaGUuY2F0YWxpbmEuY29yZS5TdGFuZGFyZFNlcnZpY2UKbWV0aG9kOiBzdG9wSW50ZXJuYWwKbG9nZ2VyOiBvcmcuYXBhY2hlLmNhdGFsaW5hLmNvcmUuU3RhbmRhcmRTZXJ2aWNl
2023-05-15T11:33:34.988862618Z x-ms-applog:Informational:base64:RGVzdHJveWluZyBQcm90b2NvbEhhbmRsZXIgWyJodHRwLW5pby04MCJdCnNvdXJjZTogb3JnLmFwYWNoZS5jb3lvdGUuQWJzdHJhY3RQcm90b2NvbAptZXRob2Q6IGRlc3Ryb3kKbG9nZ2VyOiBvcmcuYXBhY2hlLmNveW90ZS5odHRwMTEuSHR0cDExTmlvUHJvdG9jb2w=
2023-05-15T11:33:35.330861970Z 2023-05-15T11:33:35.313Z  WARN 92 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
2023-05-15T11:33:35.407655774Z 2023-05-15T11:33:35.407Z  INFO 92 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 
2023-05-15T11:33:35.407737474Z 
2023-05-15T11:33:35.407747974Z Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695403212Z 2023-05-15T11:33:35.598Z ERROR 92 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695474212Z 
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695481012Z org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695486012Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695491212Z  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:578) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar!/:6.0.6]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695516812Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695522412Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695526712Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695530612Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695534512Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695538512Z  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695542512Z  at com.einfochips.smartinventory.SmartInventoryApplication.main(SmartInventoryApplication.java:13) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695546512Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695550412Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695554412Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695558312Z  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695562212Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695566112Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695572412Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695576812Z  at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695580712Z Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695584712Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695588812Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695593012Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:488) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695597212Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:210) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695601312Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695610112Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695614412Z  ... 16 common frames omitted
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695618312Z Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695622212Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:935) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695626212Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:252) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695630112Z  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695634112Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695638112Z  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695642012Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695646312Z  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695650412Z  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695654413Z  at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695658513Z  ... 21 common frames omitted
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695662213Z Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695666313Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695670213Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695674113Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695678013Z  ... 29 common frames omitted
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695681813Z Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695685713Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:935) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695689713Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695693513Z  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.695697413Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707428759Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707446959Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707452259Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util-10.1.5.jar!/:10.1.5]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707456659Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707460759Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707464759Z  ... 29 common frames omitted
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707482359Z Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707488859Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707493059Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707496959Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707503659Z  ... 37 common frames omitted
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707507559Z Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707511659Z  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707515559Z  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707519659Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707523559Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.707527459Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760145767Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util-10.1.5.jar!/:10.1.5]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760182468Z  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760188268Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760192768Z  ... 37 common frames omitted
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760196968Z Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760201168Z  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:831) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760205168Z  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1057) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760221968Z  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1100) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760226368Z  at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getManEntry(JarFile.java:937) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760230468Z  at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.checkForSpecialAttributes(JarFile.java:1000) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760234368Z  at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.isMultiRelease(JarFile.java:389) ~[na:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760243268Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:68) ~[tomcat-util-scan-10.1.5.jar!/:10.1.5]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760247768Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:41) ~[tomcat-util-scan-10.1.5.jar!/:10.1.5]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760251768Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:393) ~[tomcat-util-scan-10.1.5.jar!/:10.1.5]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760255768Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:328) ~[tomcat-util-scan-10.1.5.jar!/:10.1.5]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760259768Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:271) ~[tomcat-util-scan-10.1.5.jar!/:10.1.5]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760263768Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:234) ~[tomcat-util-scan-10.1.5.jar!/:10.1.5]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760267868Z  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) ~[tomcat-jasper-10.1.5.jar!/:10.1.5]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760271868Z  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) ~[tomcat-jasper-10.1.5.jar!/:10.1.5]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760275668Z  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83) ~[tomcat-jasper-10.1.5.jar!/:10.1.5]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760280468Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5144) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760339168Z  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760352668Z  ... 43 common frames omitted
2023-05-15T11:33:35.760356968Z 
2023-05-15T11:33:36.279834820Z Wait for pid == 92 either returned successfully or was interrupted due to a signal 92
2023-05-15T11:33:36.315925763Z Done waiting for main process. GLOBAL_PID_MAIN=92.
2023-05-15T11:33:36.315965163Z Exiting entry script!
```

Comment: Can you edit the question with your code

Comment: Which code are you asking?

Comment: provide the code which you are trying in the question

Comment: The error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed` indicate a broken dependency. You can find a similar issue here : [Spring boot Tomcat server not starting due to zip file closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75694101/spring-boot-tomcat-server-not-starting-due-to-zip-file-closed)

Answer (score 0):

After checking your logs, I think there must be issue with the JAR file or the dependencies being used.

***Check if the below troubleshooting steps help you to fix the issue:***

Try to re-deploy your application through other ways and check if you are facing the issue.

- Also, check if you have all the required permissions for ***tomcat deployment*** in your subscription.
- Add port settings in App Service->configuration->Add Application settings as shown below:

[image]

***- Check if your application is running with the correct permissions.***

> web application failed to start

- This error could be due to the Tomcat version is not compatible with the version of Spring Boot you are using.
- And also as it is saying in the error, enable the logging in App service logs and try to run the application again.

[image]